# toggling a highlight on a checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For the following table:

```
<table id="a_grid">
  <tr id="a_row">
    <td>Choice A<input type="checkbox" id="a_box" class="box"></td>
    <td>Reason:<input type="text" id="a_text" class="reason"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b_row">
    <td>Choice B<input type="checkbox" id="b_box" class="box"></td>
    <td>Reason:<input type="text" id="b_text" class="reason"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to make it work such that when you click the checkbox, it toggles a 'control' class  to its corresponding text box that has a specific color. Trying to identify by classes so I can scale the table.

What I've tried:

```
 $(".box").change(function () {
   $(".reason").toggleClass("control", false);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your currently targeting *all* checkboxes with `.reason`, whereas you need to use the context that comes with the event, I.E. the checkbox itself. From there you can traverse up to the row, and down to the input.
- `.toggleClass()` will always remove the class, because you pass `false` as the second parameter. You can then toggle the class based on the checkbox, using the `.checked` property:

```
$('.box').change(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('tr').find('.reason')
         .toggleClass('control', $this.prop('checked'));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7qr73L5/1/)